# Как разделить элементы с одного кортежа в Python?

Tags: python, split

Код примерно такой:

```
rows2 = cur2.fetchall()

for row in rows2:
    print(row[0])
```

Получаю с SQL данные с одного кортежа в видел столбца:

```
0004
0005
```

Задача эти данные разделить и присвоить им переменные?
Пробовал через split, но он работает со строками, не получается.

```
rows2 = cur2.fetchall()

for row in rows2:
    admix = row[0]
    a, b = map(int, admix.split())
    print(a)
```

Может с начало перевести столбцы в строки, а затем использовать split? Как это сделать?

Comment: Покажите `print(repr(row))` а то непонятно ничего

Comment: Пожалуйста
два кортежа 4 значения:
`('0004', 228)`
`('0005', 112)`
Первый кортеж выдает значение столбцом: 
0004
0005
Второй кортеж выдает значение столбцом:
228
112

Comment: Вы хотите поместить `'0004'` в `a` и `'0005'` в `b`, или о чём речь?

Comment: да, все верно, именно это хочу

Comment: Ну тогда `a, b = [int(row[0]) for row in rows2]`

Comment: `    a, b = [int(row[0]) for row in rows2]:`
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Не знаю зачем вы двоеточие поставили

Comment: пытался добавить второй кортеж, не получилось
`a, b, c, d = [str(row[0]), int(row[1]) for row in rows2]`
или нужно создавать второй цикл?

Comment: Снова непонятно о чём речь и какой такой второй кортеж

Comment: row[1] - выдает значения столбцом: 228 112

Answer (score 1):

Переменные для первого кортежа:

```
a, b = [str(row[0]) for row in rows2]
```

Переменные для второго кортежа:

```
c, d = [int(row[1]) for row in rows2]
```

спасибо [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal)

Comment: `a, b = (str(row[0]) for row in rows2)` ?